# Magento 2 error module image optimizer

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.3, image

I installed the Image Optimizer for Magento 2 
I'm having trouble getting a scan on pub/media, follow the errors attached.
The error message is "Something went wrong while scan image. Please review the error log."
as per the below image 
https://i.ibb.co/4VvvDWx/1.jpg
https://i.ibb.co/m0TFSwR/2.jpg

Comment: Check this https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-image-optimizer/issues/3

Comment: but where the solution ?

Comment: Have you checked in error log?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-image-optimizer/issues/3#issuecomment-548192907

This issue is related to the function skip transparent background images. You can disable it or please check the error png image and convert it to the correct format